# How many ways to execute the tasks

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let's say you have two tasks $T1$ and $T2$. Each task has $2$ sub-tasks.
Task $T1$ has $2$ sub-tasks, $T1_1$ and $T1_2$.
$T2$: has $T2_1$, $T2_2$.

How may ways to execute these tasks if sub tasks have to be executed in their order within a task, e.g. $T2_2$ cannot be executed before $T2_1$?

Note, even the sub tasks within the task have to be in order, there are no order between the tasks. E.g. $T1_1$ could be executed and $T2_1$, $T1_2$, $T2_2$.

Imagine you have a cpu with $2$ cores which can execute simultaneously two functions, but within the function statements go in order.

Comment: The problem with this question is that THE best way to start learning combinatorics *by far* is to take some simple questions like this and actually **list out all of the possibilities *yourself* with pencil and paper.**  Until you do that, you'll be adrift, and always wondering if you should "trust" the calculations you see.

Comment: _How_ many combination should be in one set of task ? or is it you just need to show and combine all Main task in every set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, lets, instead of giving task one and two each two subtasks, rather just make it tasks $T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4$, but lets state that $T_3$ can never occur before $T_1$, and $T_4$ can never occur before $T_2$

Now, think of the different number of ways these tasks can be done as a probability tree, where each time you choose a task to complete, that task disappears, leaving behind one less task than before, meaning initially, you have $4$ tasks, then you complete one of the tasks, therefore you now have $3$ tasks left to complete. This can be expressed mathematically as a factorial function:

Number of permutations = $4! = 24$

So straight away, we can see there are 24 different ways to arrange the $4$ tasks, but now we also need to take into account that $T_3$ can never occur before $T_1$, and $T_4$ can never occur before $T_2$. So we now need to reduce the number of permutations by the number of ways in which $T_1$ and $T_3$ can be arranged, which is just $2!=2$, and also by the number of ways $T_2$ and $T_4$ can be arranged, which again is just $2!=2$, so ultimately, the number of permutations is:

$\displaystyle\frac{4!}{2!^2} = \frac{24}{4}=6$

Hopefully this answers your question fully.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! yes that's possible. Let me update the question

Comment: awesome, thanks!